# Flutter showDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

Can i showDialog inside a function without passing context?

```
void test(){
   showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
              Text("Hi"),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));    
}
```

Sorry i didn't explain very well, without passing context to function, not to showDialog

Comment: no ,I believe, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why ? an AlertDialog is shown inside the application, so inevitably you have a context.. so i don't see a problem with the context

Comment: but what is ``Alert`` ?

Comment: not important Alert

Comment: You are going to call it from button? you can pass the context

Comment: yes but i think it isn't a good pattern ? am i wrong?

Comment: I am ok with passing context on current example, instead of creating variable

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) you can't, it's required.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is **no, you can't**.

the long answer:
first, the `BuildContext` is a object type, so in order to remove conflictions between the `context` property and the `context` value we're going to rename it to `contextGotFromUI`.

**Note: `contextGotFromUI` here is just a `BuildContext` object sp we can rename it with whatever we want.**

just to not get confused by the same names

```
  void test(){
   showDialog(context: contextGotFromUI, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
              Text("Hi"),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));}
```

the `context` property in the `showDialog` is required to set from it's implementation:

```
    Future<T?> showDialog<T>({
     required BuildContext context,
     required WidgetBuilder builder,
     bool barrierDismissible = true,
     // more code
```

the `BuildContext` is an important topic to understand in flutter, to show a dialog widget on top of the screen the user is actually navigating in and seeing at any time, the `BuildContext` is what tells to show it on top of the widget with that specific context, and not other screens.

As from the [showDialog official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html):

> The context argument is used to look up the Navigator and Theme for the dialog. It is only used when the method is called. Its corresponding widget can be safely removed from the tree before the dialog is closed.

so in order to show a dialog from an external method, you need to pass a `context` that belongs to a specific widget, then use it in the `showDialog`:

```
 void test(BuildContext contextGotFromUI){
   showDialog(context: contextGotFromUI, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
              Text("Hi"),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));}
```

then from your UI where you're calling that method, pass it:

```
Widget build(BuildContext) {
// widgets
//...
 onPressed: () {
  test(context); // will show an expected dialog on the screen
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you have to create the function inside a stateful widget not in the normal classes.
in case you create the function in a normal class the context will be required!

```
void test(BuildContext context){
   showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green,),
              Text("Hi"),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));    
}
```